# Removing duplicate records with old id in SQL/ HiveQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table like below. In this table we have multiple identical records just with a different refresh_id. But we have to select records with latest refresh_id, e.g. we have to remove rows in bold/highlighted as their duplicates are available with latest refresh_id. Please help me to solve this problem using SQL/HiveQL.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTFav.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0sxc.png)

| day |  | product_id |  | refresh_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/19/2021 |  | abcd |  | 1637515839 |
| 11/19/2021 |  | abcd |  | 1637515839 |
| 11/19/2021 |  | abcd |  | 1637515839 |
| 11/19/2021 |  | abcd |  | 1637515839 |
| **11/19/2021** |  | **abcd** |  | **1637430516** |
| 11/19/2021 |  | efgh |  | 1637430516 |
| 12/11/2021 |  | ijkl |  | 1637430516 |
| **12/11/2021** |  | **ijkl** |  | **1637430250** |

Output:

| day | product_id | refresh_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/19/2021 | abcd | 1637515839 |
| 11/19/2021 | abcd | 1637515839 |
| 11/19/2021 | abcd | 1637515839 |
| 11/19/2021 | abcd | 1637515839 |
| 11/19/2021 | efgh | 1637430516 |
| 12/11/2021 | ijkl | 1637430516 |

I tried below query as an attempt but doesn't seem to help this at all, please give me some clue.

```
select mod_op.day, mod_op.product_id, mod_op.refresh_id
    , dense_rank() over(partition by mod_op.day,mod_op.product_id order by mod_op.refresh_id desc) as dense_rank
from table mod_op
where mod_op.refresh_id in (refresh_id1, refresh_id2);
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Hive - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You query is correct. You need a outer subquery to select desired rows.

```
select day,product_id,refresh_id --outer sub qry to select desired columns.
from 
(select mod_op.day, mod_op.product_id, mod_op.refresh_id
    , dense_rank() over(partition by mod_op.day,mod_op.product_id order by mod_op.refresh_id desc) as dense_rank
from table mod_op
where mod_op.refresh_id in (refresh_id1, refresh_id2)) rs
where rs.dense_rank=1 --added this to pick highest refresh id
;
```

Comment: But here I need to find historical data, so I have to find data for dense_rank=2, but it should not contain any date for dense_rank=1

Comment: isnt your requirement to pick latest one ?

Comment: no, I need historical data. This happened because of data ingestion issue which caused different refresh_id for same date.